# Kernel 4.20.8-200 headers?

Tags: fedora, kernel, virtualbox

I'm trying to run VirtualBox on my Fedora 29 machine, but it errors out.

Following it's instructions (execute /sbin/vboxconfig) yeilds:

```
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
```

Running uname -r returns `4.20.8-200.fc29.x86_64`
But I can't find this version anywhere.

Comment: Did you try to install the headers package? `sudo dnf install kernel-headers` might be all you need...

Comment: Yes I did, but it installed a mismatched version

Comment: You need to add more details to your question if you expect to get useful answers... Such as what you tried to do (e.g. install kernel-headers), which versions of kernel* packages you have installed, what the mismatch actually is, perhaps logs from vboxconfig etc. showing the problem. Right now your question doesn't really have enough information for useful troubleshooting.